# Stopping/Pickling/Unpickling/Resuming a computation

Tags: haskell, computation

Is there any Haskell way of stopping/pickling/unpickling/resuming a computation ?

Some relevant discussion about this seemed to happen [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/haskell-cafe/6EswZv9nM04/wHiwVJqry9kJ) but there was no proper solution presented. Also that discussion is old.

It would also be good, if there is some type of Event system for triggering the stopping and resuming state of the computation.

Comment: Can you include in the question an example, to show why you would need this and what the alternatives are?

Answer (score 3):

One (partial) method to do this is to operate in a `Partial`ity monad.

```
data Partial a = Done a | Step (Partial a)
  deriving Functor

instance Monad Partial where
  return = Done
  Done x >>= f = f x
  Step p >>= f = Step (p >>= f)
```

Using this, we can create computations which return in the `Partial` monad and control their evaluation.

```
reversePartially :: [a] -> Partial [a]
reversePartially = rev [] where
  rev acc []     = Done acc
  rev acc (x:xs) = Step (rev (x:acc) xs)

runN :: Int -> Partial a -> Either (Partial a) a
runN _ (Done a) = Right a
runN 0 (Step p) = Left p
runN n (Step p) = runN (pred n) p

run :: Partial a -> a
run (Step p) = run p
run (Done a) = a
```

Here we can use `runN` to partially perform a computation, halting after at most `n` steps and returning the new, more-computed thunk or the actual result. We can also throw caution to the wind and use `run` to wait forever for a `Partial` monad to execute.

Interestingly, writing things in the `Partial` monad allows you to get some control over termination of programs. So long as each `Step` in some computation `f` is terminating, then `runN n f` is always terminating as well. This is a kind of property we'd want for function pausing.

The primary challenge of using the `Partial` monad is that it must infect every step of a computation in order to work---any pure computation inside of it will take at most one `Step`.  Another closely-tied problem is that you have to annotate your code with `Step`s manually. Finally, `Step`s have no particular guarantee to be similarly sized or have any relation to clocktime.

The last problem at least could be solved by some concurrent programming of a worker thread which can receive signals to "pause as soon as possible" in its execution of a `Partial` computation.

Finally, it's very worth noting that `Partial ~ Free Identity` which provides a nice generalization of the power of `Partial` that makes annotation of `Step`s somewhat easier.

Comment: I thought of this, but it doesn't really answer the question. The problem is the "pickling" part, which indicates storage outside of process RAM.

Comment: That's a good point and I agree. I sort of nodded to it at the end by talking about `Free` monads which are a form of defunctionalization anyway, though it'd take a lot more development there before you could get a functional pickle/unpickle since you'd have to defunctionalize your base functor as well.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow package offers a sort of solution to this: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Workflow

As the documentation describes: "The computation can be restarted at the interrupted point thanks to its logged state in permanent storage. The thread state is located in files by default. It can be moved and continued in another computer."

Under the hood it uses a sort of writer/state monad that tracks your actions as of type `Stat` where `Stat` is a way of tracking your progress and context as follows:

```
data Stat =  Running (M.Map String (String, (Maybe ThreadId)))
          | Stat{ self      :: DBRef Stat
                , wfName    :: String
                , state     :: Int
                , recover   :: Bool
                , timeout   :: Maybe Integer
                , lastActive:: Integer
                , context   :: (Context, B.ByteString)
                , references:: [(Int,(IDynamic,Bool))]
                , versions  :: [IDynamic]
                }
           deriving (Typeable)
```